# Display of the few pages on the main page at the Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with the display of the few pages on the main page at the Wordpress. Exactly, I want to display page with using template - I would like get the HTML code but the only solution is working That is:

```
echo wp_remote_retrieve_body (wp_remote_get (get_permalink ($ page_id)));
```

I really want to know Is that a better way to get this code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main page in wordpress in one with extension .php. If you want to see a page before, save a page: index.html

Then the main page is index.html

Regards